# Identify all occurrences of a 16 digit number within the string - php

Tags: php

If I had a string for example "Hello, my customer number is x and I need to log a fault" where x is always a 16 digit number. I need to identify all occurrences of a 16 digit number within the string.

What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: Use regular expression to find that number. Tag this question with regular expression tag.

Comment: You should use regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression of the form `[0-9]{16}` (a digit, 16 times). For example:

```
$message = "blah blah 1024590293404182 blah";
$numbers = array();
preg_match('/[0-9]{16}/', $message, $numbers);
```

After this, `$numbers` is an array with all the 16-digit numbers from `$message`. You can also do:

```
$message = "blah blah 1024590293404182 blah";
$numbers = array();
if (preg_match('/[0-9]{16}/', $message, $numbers)) {
    // There is a 16-digit number in $message, and all numbers are in $numbers
} else {
    // No 16-digit number was found
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php.

Comment: thanks, but this seems to be only matching the first occurrence of a 16 digit number

Comment: @mrsmith then use preg_match_all().

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/[\\d]{16}/', $subject)) {

} else {

}
```

Try out this code. It should find 16 digits number inside the string.